# the icon not appear in PaginatorTamplate jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, data-export

*i would be add the icon in the header of my daTaTable but when i execute the programme the icon not display he's appear {Exporters}. i use jsf 2.2.0 primeFaces 5 eclipce juno 
this is my code view :

```
  <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="produit" editable="true" value="#{produitBean.produits}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters} "
      paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
     <h:commandLink>
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="excel.png" width="24" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="produits" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exact version of PrimeFaces are you using? This feature is only available from version 5.0.2:

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3194

For example, if you have the 5.0 community version you won't be able to use that.

Comment: mrganser yes i have version 5.0

Comment: @khadija ok, if you are not a pro/elite user you can wait until they release next community version (5.1) which is going to be soon I believe, or if you really want it now, you can build it yourself from sources: [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/BuildingFromSource)

Comment: i add the new version of primeFaces the icon appear but i would be it localisated in right of my datatable